# Cannot Store and Retrieve data using AsyncStorage in React native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native,I was just learning react native now,i was trying to store values from TextInput and store into AsyncStorage by clicking Register Button.I am trying to get that value by clicking Get Button.I can't get value from AsyncStorage.getItem('value'), later I was thought wether data is storing in AsyncStorage.setItem('name','value').Somebody look at this code and tell me the answer where i was made mistake.

```
export default class AsyncStorageEample extends Component 
{

constructor(props)
{
super(props)

  this.state= { name:'', email:'',mobile:''}
  this.onRegisterPress=this.onRegisterPress.bind(this)
  this.onRetreive=this.onRetreive.bind(this)

}

onRegisterPress()
{
   let name=this.state.name
   let email=this.state.email
   let mobile=this.state.mobile

   AsyncStorage.setItem('name',name)
   AsyncStorage.setItem('email',email)
   AsyncStorage.setItem('mobile',mobile)

   this.setState({name: name, email:email,mobile:mobile})


}

onRetreive()
{
  var user;
  user= AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value) => this.setState({ 'name': value }))

  Alert.alert('Name:'+user);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.Signupform}>

        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Name </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.tInRegister} onChangeText={(text)=>   this.setState({name: text})} value = {this.state.name}/>

        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Email </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.tInRegister} onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({email: text})} value= {this.state.email} />

        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Mobile </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.tInRegister} onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({mobile: text})} vaue= {this.state.mobile} />

        <Button 
         onPress={this.onRegisterPress.bind(this)}
         title="Register"
         color="#841584"
        />

        <Button
        style={styles.get}
        onPress={this.onRetreive.bind(this)}
        title="Get"
        color="#841584"/>
        </View>
        </View>
    );
 }
 }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       container: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',

            backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        },

        tInRegister: {
            fontSize: 16,
            height: 40,
            color: '#800080'
        },
        textStyle: {
            fontSize: 16,
            color: '#800080'
        },
        Signupform: {
            width: 400,
            height: 100,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginTop: 10,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginRight: 10

        },
        get:
        {
          marginTop:20,
        },


});

       AppRegistry.registerComponent('AsyncStorageEample', () =>     AsyncStorageEample);
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage is an asynchronous operation. So it should be done with 'async - await' .

Try the following code

```
async onRetreive() {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
    Alert.alert('Name:'+user);
}
```

Comment: @sowmya Even in [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) 'async-await' is used. I don't know how you missed it.

Comment: Fine. Happy coding.

Comment: Wrap this in a try and catch as it can throw.